# redirect_to an action is not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In product controller I have this code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to category_category_details_path(:product => @product.category_id), notice: 'successfully created.' }
end
```

In category controller I have this code:

```
def category_details
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { }
  end
end
```

But the above redirecting is not working. No error show in terminal but do not redirect. How to make this work?

Comment: Please show relevant log fragment.

Comment: You have given 2 controllers. Which one you are saying is not redirecting?. Being not said specifically about the issue, no one can answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably put the wrong path in.  do `rake routes | grep details` on the command line and you should see the right path.  At a guess it might be `category_details_category_path`.

There's something else weird:  you're passing through a "product" parameter but setting it to the id of a category.  Maybe that's what's meant to happen but if so then you're creating a confusing situation.  Maybe it's meant to be `(:product_id => @product)` or `(:category_id => @product.category_id)`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be best providing the log details for the response (from Marek Lipka's comment). It will be good to show this with your `routes.rb` file too

But in the meantime, have you tried [`format.any`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html) as a test?

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.any { redirect_to category_category_details_path(:product => @product.category_id), notice: 'successfully created.' }
end
```